# kafak brokers are not rechable from the memsql ops in windows machine?

Tags: apache-kafka, metadata, singlestore

While i'm connecting memsql to kafka using Docker... I'm unable to fetch the data that i'm pushed into kafka topic....

I'm getting error like

```
ERROR 1933 ER_EXTRACTOR_EXTRACTOR_GET_LATEST_OFFSETS: Cannot get source metadata for pipeline. Could not fetch Kafka metadata (are the Kafka brokers reachable from the Master Aggregator?)
```

Comment: Please show your Docker configs

Comment: version: '2'

services:

  memsql:

    image: 'memsql/cluster-in-a-box'

    ports:

      - 3306:3306

      - 8080:8080

    environment:

      LICENSE_KEY: ${LICENSE_KEY}

      START_AFTER_INIT: 'Y'

Comment: Please [edit] your question

Comment: It means that MemSQL doesn't have connection to Kakfa.  
Does Kafka run on docker compose also or as external cluster?